# How to perform checks before the creation of a resource in REST?

Tags: rest

My use case if the following: my application will allow to create some configuration on remote systems which are complex and take some time to proceed. So we let users input the data and then the application performs a series of checks. If the checks are successful, we let the user actually create the configuration.

This use case is represented using a REST API. How would you represent it using REST?

For instance, I have a Network resource. Creating a new network will be done by sending a PUT request to /network. But how do you perform the checks in a RESTful way?

For now I have a NetworkPreview resource. To perform a check, you send a PUT request with exactly the same parameters to /network/preview. But that does not feel right, as I fail to see why a "preview" is a real resource. It is just a series of checks.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just return a 400 or similar from `PUT /network` if the checks fail? Also, `PUT /network` creates a *user*?

Comment: I agree that could be a reasonable option. In our case, we want to let the user verify the checks went ok before confirming the creation. The checks return some additional information that the user might not be aware of before, so they might want to change their first input instead of proceeding with the operation.

Comment: Basically, the result of the checks also describes everything the system will do when the user confirms. If the user disagrees with some of those elements, they can still change their mind and their input.

Comment: Well, HATEOAS dictates that you PUT the data and the server returns a response that contains a) the additional information you describe and b) the URL to hit if the user wants to finalize the creation. Solves the problem of "not-quite-a-resource" by making the second URL totally opaque to the client.

Comment: So you say that the current design is good, the only thing is that /network/preview should return the next URL as part of the response?

What about the fact /network/preview does not look like a resource?